# how to insert a new line after or before a given line number in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create a new line of data within an array where the line number = a given number

pseudo code

```
$info = array("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner");
$target = "1"; //define where i want new data, pushing other data down
$inject = "Brunch";

$newarray = somefunction($info, $target, $inject);
```

$newarray now looks like

```
[0]Breakfast
[1]Brunch
[2]Lunch
[3]Dinner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`array_splice` function](http://php.net/array_splice) to do so:

```
array_splice($info, $target, 0, $inject);
```

But note that `array_splice` modifies the original array. So you would need to copy the array first and operate on the copy:

```
$newarray = $info;
array_splice($newarray, $target, 0, $inject);
```